# ABPFramework 8.x Multi Layouts and Angular: can create normal API controller like WebApi?

Tags: abp-framework

ABP Framework v.8.x Multi Layers + Angular and login from AzureAD. After login successfully, Angular UI is authenticated with ABP's Token.

I need to get Azure's Token which stored in HttpContext to ship to Angular UI a fews data like Name, Roles, Avatar but I can't create API controler like WebApi? How can I do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQawx.png)

Many thanks, Bill Pham,